# Telegram. Не публикуются посты из канала в канал

Tags: python, telegram

Написал скрипт на python, суть его в том, чтобы он публиковал посты из определенного Телеграм канала в мой Телеграм канал. В Pycharm ошибок нет, но скрипт не выполнят работу.
Что я мог упустить? Заранее благодарю!

```
    import telebot
    import requests
    import time
    
    bot_token = "tokenbot"
    target_channel_id = "@mychanel"
    source_channel_id = "@namechanel"
    
    bot = telebot.TeleBot(bot_token)
    
    def copy_posts(messages):
        for message in messages:
            if "text" in message:
                text = message["text"]
                bot.send_message(target_channel_id, text)
            elif "photo" in message:
                photo = message["photo"][-1]["file_id"]
                bot.send_photo(target_channel_id, photo)
    
    def get_new_posts():
        response = requests.get(f"https://api.telegram.org/bot{bot_token}/getUpdates")
        data = response.json()
        return data["result"]

    while True:
        new_posts = get_new_posts()
        copy_posts(new_posts)
        time.sleep(60 * 5)
```